# Creating object using data from txt file

Tags: java, object, text-files

*My txt file looks like: -*

Type: Warrior

Health: 100

Level: 1

Experience: 0

Max health: 100

Potions  - Small : 2

```
     - Medium : 1

     - Large : 0
```

*I want to create object using numbers after ":" character (hero = new Warrior(health, level, experience, maxHealth, inventory) my code is not working at all. Here I have my codes. when I print the Arraylist, it does print out all the element I needed. But except it doesn't do anything and also it does not show any error message.
Thank you)*

```
private void loadHero() throws IOException {
        try {
            File file = new File("hero.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            ArrayList<String> listOfVariables = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;

           int count = 0;
           while((line= reader.readLine())!=null){
               String[] val = line.split(":");
               String members = val[1];
               listOfVariables.add(members);
               count+=1;
           }
            String name = listOfVariables.get(0);
             int health = Integer.parseInt(listOfVariables.get(1));
             int level= Integer.parseInt(listOfVariables.get(2)) ;
             int experience= Integer.parseInt(listOfVariables.get(3));
             int maxHealth= Integer.parseInt(listOfVariables.get(4));
             int smallPotions= Integer.parseInt(listOfVariables.get(5));
             int mediumPotions= Integer.parseInt(listOfVariables.get(6));
             int largePotions= Integer.parseInt(listOfVariables.get(7));

             Inventory inventory = new Inventory(smallPotions, mediumPotions, largePotions);
             hero = new Warrior(health, level, experience, maxHealth, inventory);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the error message? Or what is the erroneous behaviour? And why do you use a `List` for the values instead of a of `Map` ? Not to mention that your `listOfVariables` is a list of values …

Comment: This line `String members = val[1]` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when it reads the line "Potions -" because there is no ":" character on that line and therefore the `val` array will contain only one string "Potions -" which will be `val[0]`. As @tquadrat said, describe your error message so that your issue could be understood.

Comment: @tquadrat, there is no error message at all, yes the listOfVariables if the arrayList of the values that I need to create (Warrior)hero object.

Comment: @AmalK, Sorry I made mistake while pasting my txt file, I have corrected it. There is ":" character in each line.

Comment: @SagarThapaChhetry There is no output because you have not included any print statements. The code is working. The object is created but is never displayed. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is **working fine** but you need to add a **print statement** otherwise the created object will never be displayed after it has been created sucessfully.

Method:

1. Override `toString()` in you model classes and choose a nice layout for displaying the data.
2. Add a print statement after the creation of your object. (Example `System.ou.println()`).

I hope I could help you, keep your great work up!